Can a liferay hook xml contain 2 servlet-filter configurations?
I have created a hook in liferay with given xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 7.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_7_2_0.dtd">

<hook> 
     <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request Filter</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>package.SecurityFilters</servlet-filter-impl> 
    </servlet-filter>
    
    <servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request Filter</servlet-filter-name>       
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>       
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </servlet-filter-mapping>
 
    <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>package.DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-impl>
    </servlet-filter>

    <servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/documents/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </servlet-filter-mapping>
</hook>

After deploying this hook I am seeing this exception:
The content of element type "hook" must match "(portal-properties?,language-properties*,custom-jsp-dir?,custom-jsp-global?,indexer-post-processor*,service*,servlet-filter*,servlet-filter-mapping*,struts-action*)".

If I comment out one or the other servlet config the hook is deployed correctly and I am able to see in the logs that the filters are working.
From the DTD I understand the I should be able to put many servlet-filter and servlet-filter-mapping, so I am not sure where did I made the mistake.
DTD documentation
If an element name in DTD is followed by the star [*], this element can occur zero, once or several times.

Is it possible to create 2 servlet filters in one liferay hook?

please add comments with down votes

Finaly I have managed to put 2 filters. The only problem was really my xml. I I was not aware that the order of elements in XML matteres.
I was puting element in order:

servlet-filter
servlet-filter-mapping
servlet-filter
servlet-filter-mapping

which was causing  xml validation exception.
Puting elements in order:

servlet-filter
servlet-filter
servlet-filter-mapping
servlet-filter-mapping

solved the issue. Both filters are working. What helped me during the process was the online validator: https://www.truugo.com/xml_validator/ where I was able to track the problem easier than redeploying the app.
Final xml looks like:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 7.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_7_2_0.dtd">

<hook> 
     <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request Filter</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>package.SecurityFilters</servlet-filter-impl> 
    </servlet-filter>
    
    <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>package.DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-impl>
    </servlet-filter>
    
    <servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request Filter</servlet-filter-name>       
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>       
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </servlet-filter-mapping>
   
    <servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Servlet Request DocumentDownloadFilter</servlet-filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/documents/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    </servlet-filter-mapping>
</hook>


According to the DTD you're on Liferay 7.2 - consider ignoring the 6.x hook concept and go with an OSGi ServletFilter:
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "before-filter=Auto Login Filter",
                "dispatcher=REQUEST",
                "servlet-context-name=",
                "servlet-filter-name=My Servlet Filter",
                "url-pattern=/change/me"
        },
        service = Filter.class
)
public class BladeServletFilter extends BaseFilter {

    @Override
    protected void processFilter(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws Exception {

        // implement your own logic here
    }
}


unfortunately I do not have @Component from osgi on my classpath. only spring stereotype  Component, which does not have "immediate, property, service)

I have added dependency for osgi annotations and tried to add this filter in a way from expample from the link which you sent. Unfortunately the filter is not being initialized via the hook and therefore it is not processing any request.

You wouldn't deploy an OSGi component as a hook (war), but as an OSGi bundle (jar)

Changing the hook into bundle unfortunately was not possible at the moment. Luckily I have found solution to my problem, which appeared to be trivial mistake in xml. Anyhow I give votes up for your valid answer as well.
